# How to properly use array values from SQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql

The following code gives the result as an array

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "54654gt354t54t", "g543tg3g54g4g", "45t54g5wg4g44");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 
   $sql = 'SELECT status, phone, COUNT(*) AS count FROM people WHERE phone=1234567890 GROUP BY phone, status';
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

   echo $row['count'];



        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

The result is "141051"
14, 10, 5 and 1 are different values.Consider 
14 as value 1, 10 as value 2 and so on...
how to use them properly ?
like
`echo $value1;` should print the number "14" from this array.

Each of that value represent a status, consider it is a shopping site.
1 pending confirmation
2 confirmed
3 shipped

If the phone "1234567890" has three "2" in his status column, that means there are three confirmed orders. is there is file "3" in the columns, there are three shipped orders. so using a simple HTML code is not a solution.
I want to display is like this

```
echo "confirmed orders";
echo $value2;
echo "<br/>Shipped orders";
echo $value3;
```

I am trying to learn this, a simple example will help me a lot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQUn2.png)

array

Array ( [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQUn2.png) => 2 [1234567890] => 2 [14] => 2 ) Array ( [2] => 2 [1234567890] => 2 [10] => 2 ) Array ( [3] => 2 [1234567890] => 2 [5] => 2 ) Array ( [4] => 2 [1234567890] => 2 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQUn2.png) => 2 )

Comment: You can just print out a new line, or in HTML its `<br />`, this can be something like this `echo $row['count'] . '<br />';`

Comment: As it is being fetched as array, 

echo $row["status"] will display status, echo $row["phone"] will display phone, echo $row["count"] will display count,

Comment: @ROOT, I was not enough clear in the question. each of that value represent a status.
updated in the question, please check.

Comment: @Nava Bogatee, I want tot display each number desperately. if I use echo $row["status"], it will show "141051", what if I only want to display the 14 and 5?

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot of the output? Or the structure of the table..

Comment: @Nava Bogatee, I have updated the question with my full code, and added a screenshot of the table structure. result is the numbers "141051" in my server and the result for the example given here will be different.

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp) takes an optional 2nd argument which indicates whether you want the `resulttype` as `MYSQLI_ASSOC` or `MYSQLI_NUM`

I updated the following in your code

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
   echo "Phone = $row[phone] Status=$row[status] Count = $row[count] <br>";
}
```

and got the following output

```
Phone = 1234567890 Status=2 Count = 3 
Phone = 1234567890 Status=3 Count = 2
```

If you just want the count column, just use`echo $row[count]`

I hope it works. In the future to avoid confusion please share the full source  code, screenshot of your output and the table data (prefably in text format)

Comment: If I use the `echo $row[count]`, I will be getting "32", but I want use the "3" and "2" separately. in my side, the result is "141051" 14, 10, 5 and 1 are different values. I am sorry that I didn't post the exact table data.

Comment: I doubt you're getting '32' and not 3 and 2 is that you're not adding line breaks in between the iteration in the loop.

Look how I added <br> tag at the end of echo statement inside the while loop.

Comment: adding <br> is not helpful. because 3 and 2 represent different conditions. for example  3 is the count of cancelled orders and 2 is the count of shipped orders. if I use  "<br> Shipped", it will show 
Shipped 3 
Shipped 2